# Command to change foreign key from uni to mul

Tags: mysql

i have a foreign key that is set to unique and I need it set to mul. What is the command t do that?

Comment: You mean multiple columns or MUL what?

Comment: need to make it a non-unique index

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `instructorstudentgroup` (
  `InstructorStudentGroupID` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Instructor` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClinicalID` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InstructorStudentGroupID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ClinicalID` (`ClinicalID`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: I disabled the foreign key checks dropped the table then recreated it with just Key ClinicalID (ClinicalID)

Comment: Check the answer below please

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to alter your unique key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instructorstudentgroup 
( InstructorStudentGroupID int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Instructor varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
ClinicalID int(2) DEFAULT NULL, 
Location varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (InstructorStudentGroupID), 
UNIQUE KEY ClinicalID (ClinicalID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And this is to drop your ClinicalID

```
alter table instructorstudentgroup drop index ClinicalID;
```